# Python: String reverse stops halfway

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, reverse

I'm writing a function to reverse a string, but it doesn't complete it till the end. Am I missing something here?

```
def reverse_string(str):
    straight=list(str)
    reverse=[]
    for i in straight:
        reverse.append(straight.pop())
    return ''.join(reverse)

print ( reverse_string('Why is it not reversing completely?') )
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman for the clarification. I was just curious why this logic is failing. yeah, that's a bad idea; the code challenge from the website had 'str' and i didn't change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you `pop` elements from the original and thereby change the length of the list, so the loop will stop at half the elements.

Typically this is solved by creating a temporary copy:

```
def reverse_string(a_str):
    straight=list(a_str)
    reverse=[]
    for i in straight[:]:  # iterate over a shallow copy of "straight"
        reverse.append(straight.pop())
    return ''.join(reverse)

print(reverse_string('Why is it not reversing completely?'))
# ?yletelpmoc gnisrever ton ti si yhW
```

---

However in case of reversing you can use already existing (easier) alternatives:

Slicing:

```
>>> a_str = 'Why is it not reversing completely?'
>>> a_str[::-1]
'?yletelpmoc gnisrever ton ti si yhW'
```

or the `reversed` iterator:

```
>>> ''.join(reversed(a_str))
'?yletelpmoc gnisrever ton ti si yhW'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @MSeifert. Why does the loop stop half-way, any specific reason?

Comment: Assume the list is 4 items long before the loop. In the first iteration it gives the first item, then you pop one item (new length = 3), the next iteration it gives you the second item and pops one more (new length = 2), the next iteration the loop would give you the third item but because the list has only length 2 now it stops there. The fact that it halves the list is because you pop one element in each iteration (thereby consuming 2 items per iteration). :)

Comment: `while straight` makes more sense than iterating over a copy, considering the elements of the copy are completely ignored anyway. Just pop until there's nothing left.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use steps iterator to reverse a string

```
print('hello'[::-1])
```

Will reverse the string

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to reverse:

```
>>> 'my string'[::-1]
'gnirts ym'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop from the last index of list to zero index and then `append` in another list and then `join` to get reverse tring.

```
def reverse_string(str):
    straight=list(str)
    print straight
    reverse=[]
    for i in range(len(straight)-1,-1,-1):
        reverse.append(straight[i])
    return ''.join(reverse)


print ( reverse_string('Why is it not reversing completely?') )
```